# Consider $X(s,v)=c(s)+r(N(s)\cos(v)+B(s)\sin(v)) $. Show: X regular if and only if $r< \frac{1}{k(s)}$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

> Let $c : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $ be a space curve ( parameterized by arc length ) with curvature $k(s) \neq 0 \ \forall s \in (a,b) $. 
>   Consider the tube $X : (a,b) \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^3  $ with: 
>   $$X(s,v)=c(s)+r(N(s)\cos(v)+B(s)\sin(v)) $$
>   Remark: $N(s)$, $B(s)$  the normal, the binormal vector of $c(s)$. Moreover $r>0$.
>
> *Show that* : $ X $ is regular if and only if $r< \frac{1}{k(s)} \forall s \in (a,b)  $.

So first of all we know that $c$ is parameterized by arc length. So we can use frenet equations: 
$c'(s) = T(s) = k(s)N(s)$ , $N'(s) = -k(s)T(s) + \tau(s)B(s)$ and $B'(s) = -\tau(s)N(s)$.  Remark: $\tau$ is torsion.

We want that X is regular ( if and only if $k(s) \neq 0 \ \forall s \in (a,b) $). So we have to show that $D_X(s,v)$ has full rank. If I'm right the first column of $D_X(s,v)$ is $c'(s) +
r(N'(s)\cos(v)+B'(s)\sin(v))$ and the second one is $r(-N(s)\sin(v)+B(s)\cos(v))$. My idea is to show that these two vectors are linearly independent ( maybe with help of frenet?),  which means that $D_X(s,v)$ has full rank. I hope that you can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given the so-called tubular map

$X(s, v) = c(s) + r(N(s) \cos v + B(s) \sin v), \tag 1$

where $c(s) \in \Bbb R^3$ is parametized by its arc-length; as such, it is also a *unit-speed* curve, as is well-known; thus we have the unit tangent vector

$T(s) = c'(s), \tag 2$

and in accord with the *Frenet-Serret* view of things we also have the unit normal vector $N(s)$ and curvature scalar $\kappa(s)$ defined by

$T'(s) = \kappa(s) N(s), \tag 3$

and a third vector $B(s)$, the binormal of $c(s)$,

$B(s) = T(s) \times N(s); \tag 4$

the *Frenet-Serret* equations affirm that

$N'(s) = -\kappa(s) T(s) + \tau(s) B(s), \tag 4$

and

$B'(s) = -\tau(s) N(s), \tag 5$

where $\tau(s)$ is known as the torsion of $c(s)$.  $N(s)$ and $B(s)$ are the vector fields along $c(s)$ used in the definition (1) of $X(s, v)$.

The tubular surface $X(s, v)$ has two distinguished tangent vector fields, each corresponding to one of the parameters $s$, $v$; they are

$X_s(s, v) = \dfrac{\partial X(s, v)}{\partial s}, \tag 6$

and $X_v(s, v) = \dfrac{\partial X(s, v)}{\partial v}; \tag 7$

these vector fields $X_s(s, v)$ and $X_v(s, v)$ are tangent to the curves in the surface $X(s, v)$ on which $v$ and $s$ are respectively constant.

The surface $X(s, v)$ is *regular* precisely when the two vector fields (6) and (7) are linearly independent; to investigate further what regularity means in terms of the vectors $T(s)$, $N(s)$, and $B(s)$, we may compute $X_s(s, v)$ and $X_v(s, v)$ directly from (1), using (2)-(5):

$X_s(s, v) = c'(s) + r(N'(s) \cos v + B'(s) \sin v)$
$= T(s) + r((-\kappa(s)  T(s) + \tau(s) B(s)) \cos v - \tau(s) N(s) \sin v)$
$= (1 - r\kappa(s) \cos v)T(s) + r\tau(s) B(s) \cos v - r\tau(s) N(s) \sin v, \tag 8$

$X_v = -rN(s) \sin v + rB(s)\cos v; \tag 9$

comparing (8) and (9) we find the curious relationship

$X_s(s, v) = (1 - r \kappa(s) \cos v) T(s) + \tau(s) X_v(s, v); \tag{10}$

furthermore, we see that

$T(s) \cdot X_v(s, v) = 0, \tag{11}$

since

$T(s) \cdot N(s) = 0 = T(s) \cdot B(s); \tag{12}$

therefore $X_s(s, v)$ and $X_v(s, v)$ are linearly independent exactly when

$(1 - r\kappa(s) \cos v)T(s) \ne 0; \tag{13}$

or, since $T(s) \ne 0$,

$1 - r \kappa(s) \cos v \ne 0; \tag{14}$

or

$r \kappa(s) \cos v \ne 1. \tag{15}$

We note that $r \kappa(s) > 0$; now if for any value of $s$,

$r \kappa(s) \ge 1, \tag{16}$

then by selecting $v_0 \in \Bbb R$ such that

$\cos v_0 = \dfrac{1}{r \kappa(s)} \le 1, \tag{17}$

which is always possible since the range of the variable $v$ is $\Bbb R$, we have

$1 - r \kappa(s) \cos v_0 = 0, \tag{18}$

at which point $(s, v_0)$ $X_s(s, v)$ and $X_v(s, v)$ become linearly dependent and the surface $X(s, v)$ ceases to be regular.  Therefore we must have

$0  < r\kappa(s) < 1, \tag{19}$

or

$r < \dfrac{1}{\kappa(s)}, \; \forall \; s \in (a, b). \tag{20}$

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. Two little remarks and one question: $1)$ you said that ( in (8) )  $ T(s) + r((-\kappa(s)  T(s) \cos v + \tau(s) B(s)) \cos v - \tau(s) N(s) \sin v)$ , but you mean $= T(s) + r((-\kappa(s)  T(s) + \tau(s) B(s)) \cos v - \tau(s) N(s) \sin v)$ , right?  $2)$ in (10) you've forgotten $\cos$, am I right? And my question: how do we know that $r*\kappa(s) > 0$ ? I know that $ r>0 $ and I know that I have to show $r < \dfrac{1}{\kappa(s)}$. Therefore $\kappa$ has to be positive, but how can I  justify that it is impossible that $\kappa$ is negative?

Comment: You were right about the appearance or not of $\cos v$ in (8) and (10); corrected.  As for $\kappa(s) > 0$, in the *Frenet-Serret* formulation $\kappa(s)$ is generally *assumed* to be positive, or at least non-negative; I went with that assumption.  This allows us to *define* $N(s) = T'(s)/\Vert T'(s) \Vert$ when $T'(s) \ne 0$.  Then $\kappa(s) = \Vert T'(s) \Vert$.  At least that's the formulation with which I am familiar.  That's why I assumed $\kappa(s) > 0$.

Comment: Please feel free to ask me if you have any further questions.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use Frenet's formulas to express $X_s$ and $X_v$ in terms of $T, N, B$. Show that $X_s \times X_v$ is zero if and only if $rk\cos{v} = 1$.